# Tesselation/CGR Details from CATPart_CATIA_API

Tags: api, visual-c++, cad, catia, caa

I need to read the tessellation/cgr/visualisation details from a CATIA V5R18 Part file using CATIA V5R18 API.

Visualisation details such as:

1. Number of Vertices
2. Number of Triangles
3. Number of Strips
4. Number of Fans
5. Number of Normal
6. Bounding Sphere Centre and Radius

These details I have read from .cgr files using CAT3DRep/CATRep/CATSurfacicRep, but I am not able to read the same for .CATPart files.

From .CATPart with the help of CATIVisu I got CAT3DBagRep type, when I queried from PartFeatures. But to get Visualisation details I need CATSurfacicRep.

What interface should I query and from where should I query?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about R18 but for R22 and R23 if you have the CAA documentation there is an example located at: C:\Program Files\Dassault Systemes\B23\CAADoc\CAATessellation.edu. 
This example code has everything you need to get the tessellation data except normals and bounding spheres. I used this example code when I was teaching myself how to make a tessellated nurbs surface and it was quite useful for testing.